# How to create ls in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cmd, ls, dir

I want to use ls in windows command prompt and make it run the dir command.

How can I do that?

Comment: Some of the answers are quite interesting, but what exactly is wrong with the 'dir' command?

Comment: @MattDonnan I'm just used to ls and I make a *funny* face when I make it on windows. Not anymore ^^

Comment: @aF If you want ls, why don't you just use the real ls?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because it doesn't exist in windows?

Comment: Sure it does. I use it every day.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and your windows version is?

Comment: @aF. I'm using Windows 7, but I run ls on any Windows version. I'm not saying that Windows comes with ls, just that it being open source, and having good Windows ports, it's trivial to run it on Windows. Look at GnuWin32.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You could:

- create a batch file called `ls.bat` and have it contain the `dir` command only
- add the directory where the `ls.bat` file exists to your `PATH` environment variable

You could then execute `ls` from a command prompt.

Comment: why not put the ls.bat in system32 folder so you don't have to add the PATH

Comment: @David天宇Wong, it is very possible that the user may not have write access to that folder.

Comment: does this still work if you use it with args: `ls dir` ? I think you would need to modify the `ls.bat` to handle args... or you could try aliases: http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp

Comment: I like: @echo off\ndir /w %1% to get closer to ls format

Comment: excellent answer, it shouldn't be possible to comment on this ;-)

Comment: You could also install cygwin and use the ls there :>

Answer (score 310):

You can solve this question with one simple command:

```
echo @dir %* > %systemroot%\system32\ls.bat
```

Make sure you run `cmd.exe` as admin first if you are on vista and up

Comment: This is better because you can still use the dir options.

Comment: when i execute it it tells me access denied in windows 10. i gave write access to my user but yet didnt work. any idea?

Comment: It works for me in Windows10 (but you have to use a command line that has administrator privilege

Comment: while you're at it you may also want to add:  echo cls %1 > %systemroot%\system32\clear.bat

Comment: to use clear comand instead cls `echo cls > %systemroot%\system32\clear.bat`

Answer (score 42):

Its an old question but for the record:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Gives you ls and a whole lot more!

Comment: +1 `ls *` and `dir *` don't do the same thing, so aliasing dir is a bit pants.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Ignore the voting and do this.

Comment: don't forget to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` to your path

Answer (score 29):

Easiest way I have found is:

1. Install [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. Add the `bin` directory of Git to your Path variable. Mine was located in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.
3. Start a command prompt and enjoy `ls` in all its glory.

Comment: Great suggestion that gives access to full functionality of `ls` and all it's optional arguments. Just a slight update, I have installed the latest version of git for windows and the _ls.exe_ can now be found in C:\Program Files\Git\ **usr** \bin

Comment: Yes, or just start bash.exe in git folder (instead of cmd) and enjoy a ~complete shell (with ls).

Comment: git bash is hideous, i like the path option

Answer (score 18):

I have a solution but it's dirty:

Create a file named ls.bat containing only "dir".

Put it in C:\windows\system32 (or any directory in PATH env var).

That (should) works!

Edit: Something more consistent: https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 9):

If you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) installed on your system, you can install it from [Cash](https://github.com/dthree/cash), a library I wrote for Linux commands on Windows:

```
npm install cash-ls -g
```

Comment: best solution ever for linux user on windows,                                                                     `npm install cash-global -g` . Would be great to add `ls -l` as `ll` (LL) also.

Comment: Its a saviour mate

Answer (score 7):

Windows command prompt for Vista/7 will allow NTFS symbolic links, run cmd.exe as administrator then:

```
mklink ls %System%\dir.exe
```

Then set up your PATH environment variable to include the location of the link you just created.

If you want more than just the 'ls' command, you should look into [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

**EDIT- Just realized `dir.exe` is not a separate program, so this doesn't really work.  But `mklink` and cygwin are good things to know about.**

Comment: +1, I forgot to say that was windows xp but that is good for windows vista/7 :)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to have cmd recognize `ls` as an alias for `dir`, you can use the `doskey` command (from [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/49194/1420)).

This does not change the original command line parameter handling of the dir command.

Answer (score 5):

my ls.bat was below

```
@dir %*
```

that can transfer cli args

```
ls /b
ls /w
```

put it in %windir% or any directory in your %PATH% variable.

Just make sure you save the file with ANSI encoding :)

Answer (score 5):

+1 on the post above suggesting to install git for windows and add the directory bin to your path variables.

Another way I got touch, ls, and a lot of other UNIX commands working in cmd.exe on my Windows 8 and Windows 7 machines.

Go to the following site to install Cygwin

https://www.cygwin.com/install.html

Install the 32 or 64 bit version for your system. The default settings and packages should include what you need so you don't have to change anything once you get to the packages screen.

After installation, copy the Cygwin folder path to your environment path variables. For example; if you installed cygwin to C:\Cygwin, you will add the following to your environment system path variables:

;C:\Cygwin\bin

On my system I installed the 64bit version and the default folder name and path was C:\cygwin64. So i added the following to my system environment path variables:

;C:\cygwin64\bin

Restart your terminal if it's open. Then type ls and you'll see a directory listing.

See the following if you are not familiar with setting PATH environment variables:

[Superuser Link 1](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

[Superuser Link 2](https://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8/)

Answer (score 3):

you could also use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and just use the ls command directly along with all the other unix command line tools you might be used to.

Answer (score 3):

### The most easiest way is

- install git
- add `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` to your path variable

now you can use `ls`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following recipe.

1. Use `DOSKEY` and `$*` to create your `ls` command.
2. Make the command persistent by recording it in a .bat/.cmd file and add the path of the file to registry.

For example, your command may look like
         `DOSKEY ls=dir`
         `DOSKEY sublime="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text" $*`
`$*` is useful for commands that take on arguments. For example, here I like to be able to do `sublime my_code.c`.

The registry for cmd is at HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Command Processor. Create a string valued entry called AutoRun with the *full* path of the file (not the containing folder) such as `%USERPROFILE%\custom_command.cmd`. Then each time cmd is run, your command will be loaded!

You can add more useful stuffs to the batch file too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040825/3181104) for an example template.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that worked for me is to use [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), which adds multiple utilities from executable files (including `ls`, `sed`, and `grep`).

To use: download [source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/). Unzip. Add the `UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin` path to the Windows PATH variable. Start a new CMD instance.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who uses Linux Subsystem for Windows could call `ls` from the Linux bash. The following Command creates the `ls` Command in System32:

```
echo @bash -c "ls %*" > %systemroot%\system32\ls.bat
```

(The Linux Subsystem feature must be enabled/installed first)

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this guide:
https://gist.github.com/vladikoff/38307908088d58af206b

**TL;DR**: pass `/K path/to/custom/init_cmd.bat` to your "shell startup" command.

I'm using ConsoleZ as my shell wrapper, so in my case I can find the setup option in "tabs", then I set the shell path to `"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe "/K C:\cmd_init.bat""`
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcKyV.png).

Where `C:\cmd_init.bat` is the batch script containing my macros, here's what I would go for:

```
@echo off

doskey ls=dir /b
rem other macro stuff..
```

Sorry for formatting and other mistakes, this is my first time answering here.
I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create an alias in .bat or .cmd file using `doskey` key:

```
@echo off
title "ls command cmd bar"
doskey ls=echo off $T dir $* $T echo on
```

Enjoy =)

Answer (score -1):

Surely ls would not work as a unix command for the batches. If you check %1 for -l or -a etc. and all combinations of them, it would work...

Answer (score -3):

Here is my [C# source code and binary](https://gitlab.com/bytewav/LsForWindows).

Just add ls.exe somewhere and add the path to the path environment variable.

[image]

Comment: A binary is unnecessary. Just use a symlink or bat file.

Comment: !! What a complicated way to go with ..  "I need to kill that dumb fly that's been bothering me."--  "OK Frank, lock the doors and seal the windows, I've got a bug bomb, it'll take 8 hours"