# Unix command (ls) or ls-a command error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, unix

```
C:\RailsApps\Slambook> ls
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am getting this error. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: "C:\RailsApps\Slambook" does not look like Unix...

Comment: well i am working on creating slambook application on ruby on rails command server

Answer (score 4):

Your command & output is as follows:

```
C:\RailsApps\Slambook> ls
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or
external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The key issue is the error that reads, `'ls' is not recognized` as well as when your command prompt clearly shows itself to be a Windows prompt.

I am not a Windows expert, but I believe the command you are looking for is [`dir`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true).

This [question & answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362692/how-to-create-ls-in-windows-command-prompt) addresses the issue of how to create a workaround to allow `ls` to work on Windows setups.

Comment: thank you but i believe we are not on same page. i think i am asking different question