# running a python script as a command line variable

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, cmd, scripting

I am new to python and wanted to make a simple script that acted like the `ls` command in a mac/linux terminal but for cmd in windows. The code itself works and if I run the script using `python ls_script.py` in my `cmd` it works fine. However, I want to make it so that I can run it in any active directory by just typing in `ls` in my `cmd`. I made an environment variable in `cmd` called `ls` that has a value of `python ....\ls_script.py`, which assumed would work since if i were to type that exact thing in manually, it works. However, when I just type in `ls`, it gives the following error:

> "'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file."

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682057(v=vs.85).aspx  or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt ... or make a ls.bat or ls.cmd file and put it somewhere on the path ...

Comment: yeah i dont think this helps much because python runs the script if i just input the whole thing, i want it instead to run when i just type ls

Comment: if you made it an environmental variable named ls then you type `%ls%`  I would do `doskey ls=python C:\scripts\my_script.py` and use aliases (as in the link i gave you ...(2nd one))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with python, considering that the python script does what you want. The problem is getting the environment variable to work, right?

I believe this question has the answer you're looking for:

[How to create ls in windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362692/how-to-create-ls-in-windows-command-prompt)

In short, it looks to me like the way to achieve what you wanted was to not use environment variables, but to create a batch file instead.

Comment: yeah i knew about this but i'm learning python rn so i wanted to know if theres any way to do it with a python script?

Comment: You can still use your python script! The idea is you can make your ls batch file containing `python ....\ls_script.py` and then when you call ls, it will run that command, which is what you want, right?